# Passing a list of lists, as a gloabl variable to a function

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, global-variables

I have a list of 4 lists. They are initialized with `sensors = [[] for i in range(4)]`, in the beginning of my program. These lists are all global variables.

I want to pass them to a function in order to append data to them.
If i had a single variable, that i wanted to be declared as global, i would write `global myVar`, in the beginning of the function.

But given this is a list of lists, how can i pass all of them to my function as `global`?

Comment: ...`global sensors`? You only have _one_ variable there.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the var global in the main and your function.

```
global sensors
sensors = [[] for i in range(4)]


def foobar():
    global sensors
    ...do something....
```